# How do I move the number at the top of the stack to the bottom without using roll in PostScript?

Tags: postscript

I'd like to define something in the dictionary, call it top, such that it moves the number at the top of the stack to the bottom and keeps all the other numbers in place. I'd like to do this without using the `roll` operator. I've been trying things for hours but am new to PostScript and am getting frustrated since it seems like such a simple task that I could solve so quickly in any other language.

This is what I've got so far but don't know why it won't work:

```
/top {
  1 dict begin
  count 1 gt 
    {
      /first exch def
      /second exch def
      first top second
    }
} def
```

Comment: But ... *why* don't you want to use `roll`?? ... How many elements are on the stack when this needs to happen? ... Also, you have a `booleantype` followed by an executable `arraytype`, do you mean to call `if` on it? ... And `begin` should usually be paired with an `end` somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You could store everything in an array and then `get` or `getinterval` the pieces you want.

```
/first { 0 get } def
/rest { 1  1 index length 1 sub  getinterval } def

% a b c d ... n  --  b c d ... n a
/top {
  1 dict begin
    count array astore /stack exch def
    stack rest aload pop
    stack first
  end
} def
```

This could also be factored more.

```
<<
    /first { 0 get }
    /rest  { 1  1 index length 1 sub  getinterval }
    /aa    { array astore }
    /:=    { exch def }
    /spill { aload pop }
>> currentdict copy

% a b c d ... n  --  b c d ... n a
/top {
  1 dict begin
    count aa /stack :=
    stack rest spill
    stack first
  end
} def
```

`/spill` could be written several ways

```
/spill { {} forall } def
```

or even

```
% assumes array does not contain executable names or arrays
/spill { cvx exec } def
```

*Edit:* I may have misunderstood the question and shown the reverse of what was wanted. The above code does a `count -1 roll`. To do a `count 1 roll` moving the the top element to the bottom,

```
/head { 0  1 index length 1 sub  getinterval } def
/last { dup length 1 sub  get } def

% a b c ... x y z  --  z a b c .. x y
/top {
  1 dict begin
    count array astore /stack exch def
    stack last
    stack head aload pop
  end
} def
```